# unit testing : http call in controller inside directive

Tags: angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine, httpbackend

```
describe("File Upload directive", function() {
      var elm, scope,httpBackend , controller , isolateScope;

     beforeEach(angular.mock.module("fileApp"));


     beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $compile , $httpBackend) {
          elm = angular.element("<div file-upload base-upload-url='files/' ></div>");
          httpBackend = $httpBackend;
          scope = $rootScope;
          httpBackend.whenGET("fileUploadTemplate.html").respond(true);
          $compile(elm)(scope);
          controller = elm.controller;

          scope.$digest();
    }));

    it("should upload selected file",function(){
      httpBackend.flush();
      isolateScope = elm.isolateScope();
      expect(isolateScope).toBeDefined();

      isolateScope.selectedFiles=[{"webkitRelativePath":"","lastModifiedDate":"2014-05-26T11:15:55.000Z","name":"a.csv","type":"text/csv","size":131}];
      var index = 0;
      httpBackend.expectPOST("files/").respond({"fileId":67603});

      expect(isolateScope.uploadResult.length).toBe(1);
      //httpBackend.flush();
     });
    });
```

**Now, here I have situations:**

1. If I comment out `httpBackend.flush()` at the start of `it` block , isolateScope is `undefined`.
2. If I comment out `httpBackend.flush()` at the end of `it` block , the `isolateScope.uploadResult.length = 0` which suggests `httpPOST` didn't execute correctly as expected (httpBackend.flush is never called after the http call).

3.If I keep both `httpBackend.flush()` (which is not supposed to be done) , I get error as expected : `Error: No pending request to flush !`.

Can anyone please guide me ? I am a newbie to karma.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these lines too in describe block.

```
 afterEach(function() {
         $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
         $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
       });
```

or you might have not called the function in directive that instantiated the post call, otherwise it should work.

Comment: ya..got it ! missed to call the function that invokes the call. by adding start(0), its working fine. thanks